# What is the reason of this side-effect in django unittesting with sqlite?

Tags: django, unit-testing, sqlite

One of my unit-test is running Ok when executed in stand-alone but is failing when executed with the other tests of the testcase.

I am receiving an unexpected 404 status when sending a post request.

It seems that the pb is caused by a 404 exception when getting an object from database. If I comment another post on the same view in the previous test, then the problem doesn't occur anymore.

The pb seems to be caused by sqlite (memory or file). No error when using mysq but the testing process in much slower.

Any idea, what can explain this behaviour and how to correct this pb?

Comment: Do you prepopulate your database for the tests? And what is the lifespan of the database w.r.t. your testcases?

Comment: Some data is loaded thanks to fixtures. Some objects are created with model_mommy. However, the missing object is created by the production code.

Comment: Hi @luc, did you figure it out? I'm facing the same problem that tests that work in separately fail when the whole test suite is run

Comment: Hi @mrts This is quite an an old issue :) I don't remember exactly but I think that I would have posted a solution if I had one. Since that time, I try to test with the same database than the one in production. This avoid this side effect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @luc !

Answer (score 0):

there are some differences of sqlite vs mysql to keep in mind, one of which is case sensitivity. mysql queries are case insensitive by default, but sqlite ones are case sensitive. so lookups like `MyModel.objects.get(slug="Asdf")` may find the model with slug `asdf` using mysql but not using sqlite

Comment: Thanks for this comment. I am getting the object by id so the case should not be the cause of my problem.

Comment: I would have to post a full app. I can't provide a short example. But I just want to get some potential cause of side effect. I hope it is possible without diving in the code.

Comment: are you able to nail down what is causing the 404? have you tried dropping a pdb.set_trace statement in your view code and stepping through

Comment: Yes. The 404 is caused by a get_object_or_404(Moeld, id=the_id). the_id seems correct. Everything is working ok when the test is executed standalone or with mysql.

Comment: is the object definitely there? e.g. listed in Model.objects.all()